# How do I nest includes?

Tags: cross-browser, include, cross-platform, nested, crossrider

I'm using includes in my *extension.js* file and want to be able to nest other include files. For example: I want to include a file *1.js* which in turn includes *1-1.js* and *1-2.js*, and then *1-2.js* includes *1-2-1.js* and *1-2-2.js*. I can use [appAPI.resources.includeJS](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/app...) to include one level of files - but I can't seem to use it inside a resource file.

Also, why can't I just directly include files outside of the appAPI.ready callback? i.e. by simply concatenating the JS files.

Comment: Nested includes should work,
I'n not sure i've undertstood the 2nd question, if you concat your files you don't need to use includeJS.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question first, you do not have to use [appAPI.resources.includeJS](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.resources-method-includeJS) to include JavaScript files and can in fact concatenate all your include files into one file. However, since the file can grow quite quickly, this is not recommended as there is a 150K limit per file.

Regarding nesting include files, this is certainly possible. Take the following example based on your question:

**extension.js**:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  appAPI.resources.includeJS('1.js');
});
```

**1.js**:

```
console.log('1.js loaded, now loading 1-1.js & 1-2.js');
appAPI.resources.includeJS('1-1.js');
appAPI.resources.includeJS('1-2.js');
console.log('Done');
```

**1-1.js**:

```
console.log('1-1.js loaded');
```

**1-2.js**:

```
console.log('1-2.js loaded, now loading 1-2-1.js & 1-2-2.js');
appAPI.resources.includeJS('1-2-1.js');
appAPI.resources.includeJS('1-2-2.js');
```

**1-2-1.js**:

```
console.log('1-2-1.js loaded');
```

**1-2-2.js**:

```
console.log('1-2-2.js loaded');
```

The result in the console:

```
1.js loaded, now loading 1-1.js & 1-2.js
1-1.js loaded
1-2.js loaded, now loading 1-2-1.js & 1-2-2.js
1-2-1.js loaded
1-2-2.js loaded
Done
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]